# JQuery Popup working for only one item

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, popup

I have table with at least 10 entries coming from a mysql database. Each row has a button. When clicking the button, a popup with a text field is shown. The idea is to enter a bid for that item in the popup.

The script is working but only for the first element, not for the rest. How can I do this dynamically?

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#show").click(function() {
   $("#popup").show();
 });

 $("#close, #submit").click(function() {
   $("#popup").hide();
 });
});
```

```css
#popup {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 5;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <div id="close">✖</div>
      </header>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="bid.php">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="bid">Bid</label>
    <input type="text" name="bids[]" id="bids[]" size="8"/>
          <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
  <footer>
   <button type="button" id="submit">Bid Now</button>
      </footer>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

 /*This is how I trigger the popup. It is an example for one item but all the rest have the same composition*/

<td><button id="show"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>
```

Comment: My javascript isn't really good, but I can imagine it only selecting the first item if you have 10 items with `id="show"`. HTML IDs are meant to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` need to unique per element and that's the problem in your code. Convert `id` to `class` like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show").click(function() {
      $("#popup").show();
    });

    $("#close, #submit").click(function() {
      $("#popup").hide();
    });
});
```

And button code like:-

```
<td><button class="show"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>
```

A working snippet:-https://jsfiddle.net/3u2jL2rh/

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot for your time and response. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave each button a unique ID and it worked, then used the jquery selector on each ID Like so:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="popup" style="display: none;">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <div id="close">✖</div>
      </header>
      <form name="form1" method="post" action="bid.php">
        <fieldset>
          <label for="bid">Bid</label>
          <input type="text" name="bids[]" id="bids[]" size="8"/>
          <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
        </fieldset>
        <footer>
            <button type="button" id="submit">Bid Now</button>
      </footer>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

<td><button id="show"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>
<td><button id="show1"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>
<td><button id="show2"><img src="pictures/bidIcon.png" width="30" height="30"></button></td>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show, #show1, #show2").click(function() {
      $("#popup").show();
    });

    $("#close, #submit").click(function() {
      $("#popup").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of put a different ID for each row once class is better like @AliveToDie answer

Comment: @billy.farroll  OP said:- `I have a table with at least 10 entries coming from a MySQL database.` so he needs to add 10 different `id's` in his jquery code to make it work, which is a bad idea. Using `class` for this will be the best idea. Also maybe in near future, more than 10 records will come then also code will work if you use class.